# Exception handling in @Around advice in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, aspectj

I have a use case as follows:

I have to do some preprocessing before the service layer is reached and do some further operations on preprocessed data. Basically, I would like to share the processed data between `@Before` and `@AfterReturning`'s advice.

I have been going through various posts here, it seems the best way to achieve this with `@Around`, otherwise, I have to create a class-level attribute to capture the data between two different advices, and also, I have to handle thread-safety.

So resulting code snippet will look something like this:

```
    @Aspect
    public class MyAspect {
         
        @Pointcut("@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Service)")
        public void applicationServicePointcut() {
            
        }

        @Around(value = "applicationServicePointcut()")
        public Object process(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
                //Before section
                ... some preprocessing...

                
                try {
                    Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
                    //After section
                     ...save preprocessed data in db...

                     return result;
                 } catch(Exception e) {
                     throw e;
                 }
        }
    }
```

But with `@Around` advice, I seem to have two questions/doubts:

1. The code in the after section should be running only if there is no exception in service. With the above code structure, I guess, it should work fine. Please correct me, if I am wrong.
2. One more aspect with higher precedence is defined to handle exceptions with
   `@AfterThrowing` advice. I am not able to understand,  with this setting, will exception handling in the above code work fine?

   If it is not then, I guess I have to fall back to the option of defining two advices `@Before` and `@AfterReturning` in the aspect and share the data between these two with the help of the ThreadLocal variable.

Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

Comment: You are asking lots of AOP questions here, and this is of course fine. But, with all due respect, your "doubts" are so trivial in this case, that I am wondering why you did not simply try. Asking people about things which are easy to test takes longer than actually testing by yourself or - even better - writing an automated test ensuring that the aspect does what it should and that refactorings do not cause regressions in the future. You don't run untested code, do you? BTW, like I told you before, in an `@AfterThrowing` advice you cannot handle exceptions, only e.g. log them.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. The code in the after section should be running only if there is no exception in service. With the above code structure, I guess, it
>    should work fine. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

This will work fine

> 2. One more aspect with higher precedence is defined to handle exceptions with @AfterThrowing advice. I am not able to understand,
>    with this setting, will exception handling in the above code work
>    fine? If it is not then, I guess I have to fall back to the option of
>    defining two advices @Before and @AfterReturning in the aspect and
>    share the data between these two with the help of the ThreadLocal
>    variable.

The question here is why do you catch exceptions when you don't do anything with it? You can remove the try/catch.

Comment: _"Why do you catch exceptions when you don't do anything with it?"_ This is a good question. `try-catch` is only necessary, if in the error case also something needs to be done with the preprocessed data in combination with the exception data. If however the same information should be written to the DB without regard to the error situation, `try-finally` would be better. If you want to avoid duplicating code writing to DB inside both `try` and `catch`, you can also use `try-finally` and simply assign the exception to an additional variable in `catch`, optionally writing it in `finally`.